# I am facing a problem with decryption

Tags: apex, salesforce-id, encryption, crypto

My scenarion is i am encdoing the value generated from Crypto.generateDigest method and encdoing it with EncodingUtil.base64Encode .Now i am not able to decrypt it again .Can u any one help on this below is the code block how i encrypt the data. i want to decrypt back SecretAnswer1.

```
Blob blobKey         =  crypto.generateAesKey(128);
string secretanswer  =  EncodingUtil.convertToHex(blobKey).substring(0,6);
Blob b               =  Crypto.GenerateAESKey(128);
String h             =  EncodingUtil.ConvertTohex(b);
String guid          =  h.SubString(0,8)+ '-' + h.SubString(8,12) + '-' + h.SubString(12,16) + '-' + h.SubString(16,20) + '-' + h.substring(20);
Blob hash            =  Crypto.generateDigest('SHA-512', Blob.valueOf(secretanswer + guid));
string SecretAnswer1 =  EncodingUtil.base64Encode(hash);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crypto.generateDigest creates a one-way hash, or fingerprint, of a given payload. It is *not reversible*, because it does not contain the original data. Instead, use Crypto.encrypt or Crypto.encryptWithManagedIv if you expect to be able to get the data back out.